# Override a Woocomerce filter widget by a child theme or function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, layered-navigation

We are trying to override a Woocomerce widget for products filter to make the attribute name of the filter result to be in h1 tag

for SEO purposes.
We edited the code in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav-filters.php

We edited the bleow code

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_layered_nav_filters_start', $args, $instance );

            // Attributes.
            if ( ! empty( $_chosen_attributes ) ) {
                foreach ( $_chosen_attributes as $taxonomy => $data ) {
                    foreach ( $data['terms'] as $term_slug ) {
                        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
                        if ( ! $term ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $filter_name    = 'filter_' . wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $taxonomy );
                        $current_filter = isset( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ? explode( ',', wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ) ) : array(); // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
                        $current_filter = array_map( 'sanitize_title', $current_filter );
                        $new_filter     = array_diff( $current_filter, array( $term_slug ) );

                        $link = remove_query_arg( array( 'add-to-cart', $filter_name ), $base_link );

                        if ( count( $new_filter ) > 0 ) {
                            $link = add_query_arg( $filter_name, implode( ',', $new_filter ), $link );
                        }

                        $filter_classes = array( 'chosen', 'chosen-' . sanitize_html_class( str_replace( 'pa_', '', $taxonomy ) ), 'chosen-' . sanitize_html_class( str_replace( 'pa_', '', $taxonomy ) . '-' . $term_slug ) );

                        echo '<H1 class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $filter_classes ) ) . '"><a rel="nofollow" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Remove filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></H1>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now the attribute result in H1  but any plugin update will remove the h1 tag, so we tried to over ride the file by our child theme by creating a folder under my-theme/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav-filters.php but it didn't override the woocomerce plugin.

Is there away to achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to override plugin files from within a theme, at least not if the developer of the plugin hasn't exposed a hook in which you can modify the output, like with the `woocommerce_widget_layered_nav_filters_start` hook seen in the code. However, I doubt that outputting multiple `<h1>` tags will improve your SEO. What's the thought being doing that?

Comment: Our shop/categories/brands pages are missing h1

Comment: Ah I see. You need to find the WC template that is being used for the `shop/categories/brands` pages and overwrite the template. Template files within WC *can* be overwritten. Or, if the template allows it, use a hook to modify the output of the page title.